# Usage of RPDO COB-IDs

Tags: canopen

I am implementing a CANopen application. The last few weeks I have learned a lot about CAN and CANopen. One thing I can not wrap my head around is RPDOs.

I understand that an object dictionary contains dedicated space for TPDOs and RPDOs. It is clear to me that if a node needs to periodically receive a PDO, I would map an RPDO to a certain spot in the object dictionary (for example a variable at index `0x6000`).

What I don't understand is the COB-ID of these RPDO messages.

If a node periodically sends a PDO, it would be mapped in TPDO in the OD, and the logical COB-ID would be `0x180 + node ID`.
But when would a node send a message with COB-ID `0x200 + node ID` for example? Because the message type would be "Receive PDO 1", but the periodic message would be mapped in the transmitter under TPDOs, correct?

That would mean that the TPDO/RPDO in OD:
[image]

does not relate to Transmit/Receive RPDO 1 to 4:
[image]

Is my understanding correct?